# Printing the value of an int Pointer

Tags: c++, list, pointers, printing, memory-address

I have been working on this and I can't seem to get this working properly. I am returning a pointer list's last value, and I would like to print it, but It is printing a very random number. I assuming that this is the memory address of the pointer, but when I dereference it, my output still does the same thing.

My Pointerlist is a list of pointers, like: `list<int*> pointerList`

For example, this is my method returning :

```
int* end() { return (pointerList.back()); }
```

An this is how I am calling it.

```
int* totry = ca.end();
cout << *totry;
```

This is printing the Memory Adress and not the value. Does anyone have any Ideas how to solve this?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
Here is what the int pointers are pointing to:
I have a list of values such as `[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]`
And I have a list of pointers that points to different parts of that list like the following:

```
[0,4,8,12]
```

I have the Code:   `int* end() { return (pointerList.back()); }` in my Header file, and the call in my .cpp file:

int* totry = ca.end();
cout << *totry;

---

This is how I declare my pointerlist

```
    class ptrList
    {
    public:
        std::list<value_type> listOfValues;
        std::list<*int> pointerlist;
```

I fill my list pointers inside an "add" function, and I do it like this:

```
int lstsqrt = 4;
for (int a = 1; a < lstsqrt; a++)
{
   int endptr = a + (int)lstsqrt;
    pointerlist.push_back((&*listOfValues.begin() + endptr)); //( (lstsqrt - 1) + a)  );

}
```

And this is my end() method

```
int* end() {return (pointerlist.back());}
```

And this is then passed to my toTry Variable.

Comment: What is the `int*` in your list pointing to? Show us more code, please.

Comment: How can we _possibly_ know the answer to this question?

Comment: @Greg Hewgill Sorry, I added some more code to show what the int Pointers are pointing to

Comment: What is `pointerList` and what does `pointerList.back()` return a pointer to?

Comment: @SethCarnegie The PointerList is a List of int* pointers, and the pointerList.Back() is returning the int* pointer to the "toTry" variable that is calling the .end() method.

Comment: Maybe you have a wild pointer?

Comment: How can a function return a pointer to the variable that the return value of the function is being initialised to without being passed the variable?

Comment: @SethCarnegie  The end() does not take a paramater.

Comment: @SSS yes, that's the point. So it can't return a pointer to `totry` like you said it did because `totry` is just coming into existence when the function is called.

Comment: @SethCarnegie
So are you saying that I should do this?
'int* totry ;
totry = ca.end(); 
cout << *totry;'

Comment: No, you should show us the code of the function `pointerList.back`

Comment: @GregHewgill See the new edits I made. I added much more code, which is preety much everything

Comment: @SethCarnegie the PointerList.Back() method is the the Standard Library's .back() method for a list

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One problem is likely to be this line:

```
pointerlist.push_back((&*listOfValues.begin() + endptr));
```

Your `listOfValues` is a `std::list`, and therefore its values are not stored in a contiguous block of memory. So you're getting an iterator to the first element with `listOfValues.begin()`, dereferencing the iterator with `*`, taking the address of that with `&` to get an `int*`, then adding some value which points somewhere off into memory that you don't know what it is.

Try doing this instead:

```
pointerlist.push_back((&*(listOfValues.begin() + endptr)));
```

where you add `endptr` to the *iterator* (to advance it along the list), then dereference and take the address. Actually you may need to use [`advance`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/advance) instead of `+`.

Comment: a `std::list` iterator isn't random-access, is it?  So it won't support `operator+(iterator, offset)`

Comment: @BenVoigt: I can never remember (my compiler tells me when I need to know!) so I added a note about `advance`, which will take linear time but do the equivalent operation.

Comment: @GregHewgill I just tried this, but I must not be implementing it correctly. I recieve the error "Illegal Indirection", and "&" requires I-Value"

This is how I am implementing it:
`listOfPointers.push_back(&*(advance(listOfValues.begin(), endptr)) )`

Comment: Have a look at the reference for `advance` (I linked to it). It does not *return* the advanced iterator, but is a `void` function that *modifies* its first argument. So, you'll need something like: `std::list<value_type>::iterator i = listOfValues.begin(); advance(i, endptr); pointerlist.push_back(&*i);`

Comment: @GregHewgill Thanks a Million Billion! I did as you suggested, and It worked. The only additional edit made to my code is that I had to do a -1 subtraction of my endptr, because I was goin beyond the end and recieving an AssertionError that List Iterator was not dereferencable.

I appreciate the Help!